# How can I get a list starting with a,b,c instead of 1,2,3?

Tags: numbering, lists

How can I enumerate a list using lowercase letters instead of arabic numerals?

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem}` and  `\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*}]` works too

Comment: @JakeLam: Have you tried anything? Can you show us?

Answer (score 16):

Package `enumerate` does the work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[a.]
\item
First
\item
Second
\item
Third
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
......
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item Blablah 1
\item Blablah 2
\item Blablah 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

With the option `[shortlabels]`, you can use `[label=a.]`.

Answer (score 6):

A solution that doesn't require loading any packages: Issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
```

Regarding the scope of this redefinition:

- If you want the scope to be global, provide the instruction in the preamble.
- If you want the scope to apply to just one particular `enumerate` environment, encase the `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}` directive -- along with the `enumerate` environment, of course -- in a pair of `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements.

An MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% Modify only '\theenumi', leave '\labelenumi' unchanged
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello. \label{item:first}
\item Bye.   \label{item:second}
\end{enumerate}
A cross-reference to items \ref{item:first} and \ref{item:second}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no full stop after the number, as the O.P. seems to require.

Comment: @Bernard - The absence of a full stop (aka dot) is by design! The default LaTeX setup provides the macros `\theenumi` and `\labelenumi`. The latter is generally defined as `\theenumi.` -- note the dot (full stop).

Comment: So you don't like to fully stop? :o)

Comment: @Bernard - Sorry I apparently wasn't clear enough: The instruction `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}` *preserves* the presence of the full stop (aka dot) after the number/letter. I'll post an MWE to demonstrate this.